# pnpjs get sharepoint items by view issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

I'm trying to get items from large lists using pnpjs/sp

I created a promise like this:

```
  try {

// const sp = spfi();
const sp = spfi().using(DefaultInit(), DefaultHeaders(), BrowserFetchWithRetry(), DefaultParse());
const list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(ListName);
const listView = await list.views.getByTitle(ViewName).select("ViewQuery")();
const xml = '<View><Query>' + listView.ViewQuery + '</Query></View>';
const items = await list.getItemsByCAMLQuery({'ViewXml' : xml});
return items;
}
catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    return undefined;
}
```

but I can't get listView. I have this error :

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
at Proxy.<anonymous> (telemetry.js:6:31)
at moments.js:54:1
at async queryable.js:101:1
```

when I put a break point and check for the view url it seems to be good (I can access with website url + view url ).
I must do something wrong but I don't find what.

Comment: Do you mean the approach with paging is not working for you? https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#get-paged-items

Comment: I don't need Paging I need to get items from a specific view and do some stuff with so paging would be a problem.

Comment: I see. In your error message, mentioning moment.js looks suspicious - pnpjs (or spfx) do not use moment.js at all, as far as I know. Are you using some polyfill maybe? Your code also looks fine, it's unlikely that the problem is with the code you posted. I'd try putting a breakpoint at the place where the exception happens.

Comment: I have this error on vscode : 
https://tmpfiles.org/dl/275277/error.png
the url : 
'_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/views/getByTitle('TestView')?%24select=ViewQuery'

Comment: Thanks you so much  ! I finally changed my function to set sp const with 
const sp  = spfi().using(SPFx(context)); (where context is webpart context). 
it changed the url to a full one with domain and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the question comment for the answer.

my issue was to not use the spfi().using correctly :

```
spfi().using(SPFx(context))
```

where context is the webpart Context.